# PHP - Catch all exceptions and continue if $optional parameter says so

Tags: php

I'm using selenium and I have some functions that are not required in specific cases.
Example: fillText() function is going to throw an exception if my field is not present. But depending on which environment I'm working on, that field is present or not, which doesn't matter for my scenario. Fill if possible, if not move on.

```
function fillBankAccount($account, $optional = false)
{
   if($optional)
   {
    $this->fillWith($account);
    catch all exceptions and continue
    }else{
    $this->fillWith($account);
    work as usual and throw exception if not found
}
```

this would be an example. but I don't want to have duplicate code in if else, because I'd just copy a try catch and that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `try/catch`, and then test the option in the `catch` block. If the option is set, rethrow the condition, otherwise continue.

```
function fillBankAccount($account, $optional = false) {
    try {
        $this->fillWith($account);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($optional) {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
    // rest of code
}
```